# Price Range Slider in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, price, slider

Is there any custom code, which provides feature to add price slider in Layered Navigation in Magento 1?

Comment: I did this with Magento 2 not tried on M1, i used nouislider and some custom navigation.phtml. Maybe try with that and add into the template for navigation.

Comment: @harri thanks for your response... FYI, I got solution of my problem, solution is mentioned below in my answer... I hope it would help you as well..

Comment: Awesome, yeah that looks very similar to how mine worked out glad you sorted it!

Comment: thanks, and good to know that you also got resolve it!

Answer (score 4):

I got solution for my requirement, I did it in below way:

open below file:

```
app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml
```

update it according to my file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
 */
$current_catId = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($current_catId > 0) {
    $max_price = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();

    $min_price = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
} else {
    $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $result = $db->query('SELECT max(price) as max_price ,min(price)as min_price FROM catalog_product_index_price ORDER BY customer_group_id');
    $rows = $result->fetch();

    $max_price = $rows['max_price'] + 1;
    $min_price = $rows['min_price'];
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: <?php echo $min_price; ?>,
            max: <?php echo $max_price + 1; ?>,
            values: [<?php echo $min_price; ?>, <?php echo $max_price + 1; ?>],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(+ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });


    function callPriceSlider()
    {
        var priceRang = $("#amount").val();
        alert(priceRang);
        var urlSpl = document.URL.split('?');
        alert(urlSpl[0] + "-----" + urlSpl[1]);
        var redirectUrl = urlSpl[0] + '?price=' + priceRang.split(' ').join('');
        alert(redirectUrl);

        document.location.href = redirectUrl;

    }
</script>




<?php if ($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav">

        <div class="block-content">
    <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
                <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
                <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></p>
                <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                    <?php if ($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                            <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                            <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <dt>Price Slider:</dt>
                    <dd id="slider" style="height:1px"></dd>
                    <dd><p>
                            <label for="amount"><?php $this->__('Price range:');?></label>
                            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
                        </p>

                        <div id="slider-range"></div>
                    </dd>


                    <dd><label onclick='callPriceSlider()' style="cursor:pointer;"> <b><?php $this->__('Search');?></b> <label>

                                </dd>




                                </dl>

                                <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it would help you as well!

Rather than using 'Search' button you do it load page after sliding price slider.

One more thing, I want to let you know you should include all the js files from your layout xml file, I just wrote it in .phtml file because I was in hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Layered navigation`, select Manual from `Price Navigation Step Calculation` and set your configuration.
2. Now in `category > select some category > display settings > Layered Navigation Price Step` and set some value, **Price Step** is the difference between the upper limit and lower limit.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this will not add Price Slider